# replace a portion of a large array or map with a small array

Tags: java

I have a 22X12 map defined as a grid of Colors. I have seven potential objects that will appear on this grid. Each object has a small array of Colors ranging from 4X1 to 2X2. Is there any sort of math or keyword I can go on to find out how to place the smaller array within the larger array, overwriting the larger arrays values?

To give a small example of what I want to accomplish I'll use a larger integer map and a smaller integer array and what I want as the output.

Map:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Smaller Array:

```
1 0
0 1
```

Map after array is placed within:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I just need a place to get started. Is there a linear algebra concept that I can look up or is there any sort of technique for doing this kind of thing? I'm struggling to identify how to go about doing this. Thank you.

Comment: How you have implemented the Map & the Smaller Array will affect how the insertion can be done, though I'd expect a nested loop would do the job no matter the implementation.

Comment: Will it be that simple? Will that be the most efficient way?

Comment: Is there any restriction to put the smaller array into large one, because I can put it anywhere by just editing the value of the large grid!

Comment: Unless you represent your matrices with mathematical equations (which, if you want a general algorithm, rather than just a few patterns, would likely come with a ton complexity) rather than a grid of values, I don't see a faster way than looping through all the values in the smaller array and inserting these into the larger array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[][] bigMap = new int[][] {
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    int[][] smallMap = new int[][] {
            { 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1 }
    };

    overwriteArray(bigMap, smallMap, 1, 1);

    // print out the 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < bigMap.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bigMap[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + bigMap[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

static void overwriteArray(int[][] big, int[][] small, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < small.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < small[i].length; j++) {
            big[x+i][y+j] = small[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int y = 0; y < small.length; ++y)
  for (int x = 0; x < small[y].length; ++x)
    large[y + replace_y][x + replace_x] = small[y][x];
```